# Graph theory notation

Tags: graph-theory, notation

Just a quick question on graphs: how do I read the notation in this question for the edge set? I can't find any explanation in my notes or online.
[image: question]

... specifically that first half of the union. I'm guessing the union just means that the {(4,0), (3,-2), (-2,-2)...} set of edges is also included in the graph, and nothing more complicated than that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edge set is the union of two subsets. One is defined systematically: if $y=|x|+1$, there is an edge $\langle x,y\rangle$, i.e., an edge from $x$ to $y$. There are in addition five other edges, one from $4$ to $0$, one from $3$ to $-2$, and so on. Since  $|-3|+1=3+1=4$, there is an edge of the first kind is from $-3$ to $4$, written $\langle -3,4\rangle$.

Comment: Ok thanks, makes sense!

Comment: @FalseAzure: You’re welcome.